# Is there a syntax easier than JSON that allows structuring text, and can be handled in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, text-parsing

Without developing a backend solution for text-editing, I would like to allow my colleagues to edit texts that will be split into sections and subsections, like a wiki page. This means that each item can have its title and text, but also children nodes that can contain the same.

An example structure could look something like this:

```
{
    sections: [{
        title: 'First section',
        text: 'Hello world',
    }, {
        title: 'Second section',
        subsections: [{
            title: 'First child',
            text: 'Hello hello 2'
        }, {
            title: 'Second child',
            text: 'Hello hello 3'
        }]
    }]
}
```

This structure I can then easily parse in Vue or Angular to output all the sections as text articles, and also offer a table-of-contents area with quick links to each section, and they can all be labeled with their corresponding array keys.

But I'm wondering if there is anything that would allow me to achieve the same thing, but where you wouldn't have to be familiar with any syntax stuff or be able to mess up parenthesis and such. Something that would, for example, only rely on tab indentation for defining children nodes, but is then readable and parsable into a javascript object so I can still iterate over items?

Comment: You can always come up with your own syntax and write a parser. Teach them how to use a JSON Linter and use a prettier to get the indenting right.

Comment: since you're familiar with vue/angular you can create a little web app to edit objects internally

Comment: if you prefer to use indentation based language there is [`YAML`](https://yaml.org/) which is very close to json

Comment: This is likely OT for SO. Search for lightweight or [*simple markup language*](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=simle+markup+language&t=h_&ia=web), there are plenty of them.

Comment: I has to be either a data based syntax like YAML so you can iterate, but there can be pares errors,  or a loose syntax like a markup langage, but you wont be able to iterate. What's your main objective?

Comment: Did you tried Visual Studio Code ? I prefer it even having full VS subscription, quick, light, stable, syntax highlighting, etc. Would tell indenting ex. in Python is not much readable nor maintainable. In case you have good editor, no need to search workarounds...